# Does PropertyAccessor work in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I can't get this to work. Anytime I use VBScript with the .PropertyAccessor I get an error. "Ojbect doesn't support this property or method: 'PropertyAccessor' - Code: 800A01B6"

```
Const PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x370E001E"
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B"



Dim ToAddress
Dim FromAddress
Dim MessageSubject
Dim MyTime
Dim MessageBody
Dim MessageAttachment
Dim ol, ns, newMail
Dim realAttachment
MyTime = Now

ToAddress = "testing@address.com"
MessageSubject = "Auto Stats " & MyTime
MessageBody = "Stats Attached" & vbCrLf & "Produced at " & MyTime
MessageAttachment = "f:\test\LOGO.jpg"
Set Outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set ns = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set newMail = Outlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
newMail.Subject = MessageSubject
newMail.Body = MessageBody
newMail.Recipients.Add (ToAddress)
Set realAttachment = newMail.Attachments.Add(MessageAttachment)
Set oPA = realAttachment.PropertyAccessor
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_MIME_TAG, "image/jpeg"
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "myident" 'change myident for another other image
newMail.HTMLBody = newMail.HTMLBody & "<IMG align=baseline border=0 hspace=0 src=cid:myident>" 'need to match the "myident" above
newMail.Display
newMail.Send
```

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? PropertyAccessor was added in Outlook 2007.

Comment: +Dmitry Streblechenko - That was it, my developing system had Outlook 2003 installed, and kept producing the error. Once I tested the exact same script  against Outlook 2016 it worked perfectly. Thank You for your quick response and solution.